# Reactor-netty TCPClient cannot receive responses

Tags: project-reactor, reactor-netty

i'm trying to do some pre-project experience on the latest reactor-netty version that lacks of documentation; i'm using 0.8.0.M3 version.

I've developed a simple spring boot application with this tcp server that starts correctly and seems to work:

```
@PostConstruct
public void startServer() throws InterruptedException {
    TcpServer.create().
              host("localhost").
              port(1235).
              handle((in, out) -> {

                    Flux<String> fluxString = in.receive().asString().log().
                        map(text -> {
                            return "Hi server have received "+text;});  
                        return out.sendString(fluxString).then();

              } 
              ).
              wiretap().bindNow();
}
```

If i try to test using a client the interaction seems correct but i cannot receive any response:

```
int counter = 10;
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(counter);
    Flux<String> input = Flux.range(0, counter).map(i->""+i);

    TcpClient.create().
      host("localhost").
      port(1235).
      handle((in, out) -> {

          in.receive().subscribe(receiv -> {System.out.println(receiv);latch.countDown();});
                return out.sendString(input).neverComplete();

      } 
      ).
      wiretap().connectNow();
    System.out.println("waiting closure");
    boolean result = latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

looking at wiretap logging seems that the clients sends every int as string separately and the server receive only one aggregated string "0123456789" and send only one response. The Client is not receiving anything and the latch isn't decremented neither by 1 and remain at 10 (i expect at least one aggregated response to be received).

Could anyone explain what's wrong with the client and how to receive every single integer separatelly by the server?

Thx
G

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues you may need to fix.
And I would like to say this is a bit complexed for learning.

For Server:

```
    TcpServer.create()
            .host("localhost")
            .port(1235)
            .doOnConnection(c ->
                    //The origin input are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.
                    //So you need a decoder split every 1 byte as a ByteBuf.
                    c.addHandler(
                            "1ByteStringDecoder",
                            new ByteToMessageDecoder() {
                                @Override
                                protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) {
                                    out.add(in.readBytes(1));
                                }
                            }
                    )
            )
            .handle((in, out) -> {
                        Flux<String> fluxString = in.receive()
                                .asString()
                                .log()
                                .map(text -> {
                                    return "Hi server have received " + text;
                                });
                        //Since the output is quite small, you need flush it
                        return out.options(o -> o.flushOnEach())
                                .sendString(fluxString)
                                .neverComplete();

                    }
            )
            .wiretap()
            .bindNow();
```

For Client:

```
    int counter = 10;
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(counter);
    startServer();
    Flux<String> input = Flux.range(0, counter)
            .map(i -> "" + i);

    TcpClient.create()
            .host("localhost")
            .port(1235)
            .doOnConnected(c ->
                    c.addHandler(
                            //The covert input are "Hi server have received " + (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).
                            //So you need a decoder split every 25 byte as a ByteBuf.
                            "25ByteStringDecoder",
                            new ByteToMessageDecoder() {
                                @Override
                                protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) {
                                    out.add(in.readBytes(25));
                                }
                            }
                    )
            )
            .handle((in, out) -> {
                        in.receive()
                                .asString()//You need convert ByteBuf to String.
                                .subscribe(receiv -> {
                                    System.out.println(receiv);
                                    latch.countDown();
                                });

                        out.options(o -> o.flushOnEach())
                                .sendString(input)
                                .then()
                                .subscribe(); //You need to ask your client to send the data by subscribe
                        return Mono.never();

                    }
            )
            .wiretap()
            .connectNow();
    System.out.println("waiting closure");
    boolean result = latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```